# & converts to &amp; on PHP CLI (Command line) script

Tags: php, wordpress, command-line-interface

I've created a basic script to programmatically create a new post in Wordpress. The title of the post contains an ampersand and when the script is run from a browser, the title is stored correctly. If the script is run from the command line, the '&' is replaced with the special character 'amp;' when I go into Wordpress admin and view the post.

How can I avoid this happening?

Script below:

```
$my_post = array(
'post_type'     => 'post',
'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( 'Test & Go' ),
'post_status'   => 'pending',
'post_author'   => 1
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 0):

& is the special character for an ampersand. The wp_strip_all_tags functions is causing this to occur. If you remove that, the ampersand will be posted correctly.

Comment: Just tried removing the wp_strip_all_tags and changing the line to 'post_title'    => 'Test & Go' and the script has the same result.

Comment: Interesting. I'm basing my answer from my PHP knowlege rather than my (very little) knowledge of Wordpress. My next thought would be to find where the post is displayed and use str_replace. Something like this:
`$myTitle = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $myTitle);`

Comment: Same result I'm afraid

Comment: Ok, I've narrowed it down to more of an issue with Wordpress. If I'm logged in and run the PHP script from the browser, the post title is fine. If I am not logged into Wordpress and run the script from the browser, 'amp;' is in the post title.

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement to check if script is called as CLI or not, if CLI use `&amp;` if not, use &